# Logging into WiFi accesspoint using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, automation, python-requests-html, access-point

I am trying to login to my WLAN Access Point using python 2.7
Using the requests module, I was able to log in and change the SSID and Password of the router for the TpLink TL-WR740N and TL-WR841N. Both these routers have require both username and password when logging into the admin page through the browser. Here I can get a sessionID once logged into the AP. Using this session ID, further actions can be done.

```
session = requests.Session()
resp = session.get('http://<ipAddress>/.../LoginRpm.htm?Save=Save', headers=httpHeader)
## COMMENT :: session ID is contained in resp
```

```
## COMMENT : Response from above code - session ID - DIEHLXTCZFSDWSVB.
<body><script language="javaScript">window.parent.location.href = "http://<ipAddress>/DIEHLXTCZFSDWSVB/.../Index.htm";
</script></body></html>
```

However, I could not log into the TPLink TL-MR3620 router the same way. On the browser GUI, this router requires only a password; username is not required. When looking at the source, could see the code in .js format (I haven't done any JavaScript programming so far).

Need help logging into the AP.

Comment: you should rather use `DevTools` in Firefox/Chrome (tab: Network) to see all requests send from web browser to server/device when you login manually in browser. And later you should use this information with Python `requests` to send the same information - and it doesn't need JavaScript.

Comment: if server/device will really need JavaScript for login then it would be simpler to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real browser which can run JavaScript. And then you have to use Selenium to fill field in login form and `click()` button.

Comment: this JavaScript only redirect browser to `http://<ipAddress>/DIEHLXTCZFSDWSVB/.../Index.htm` and you could use this URL directly in `requests` but problem can be  `DIEHLXTCZFSDWSVB` because JavaScript may change it in every request and calculate it in some special way. First you should check if it change this value when you login again (after some delay).

Comment: Yes, the session ID DIEHLXTCZFSDWSVB changes for every login. Once a session login is successful, tasks like changing SSID/PASSWORD can be done. Issue is that the newer routers do not seem to use the same login method. They do not have a username field. Need to find a way to login first.